# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java

I am getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0` error when trying to save after inserting values from textfields into the table named `table_po`. kindly assist

```
private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                     
  try{
     if(cbo_payment.getSelectedItem().equals("Payment Mode")){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a valid payment mode before saving");
            return;
     }

     if(table_po.getModel().getValueAt(0, 0)==null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select products before saving");
            return;
      }

    for(int i=0;i<saleListCounter;i++){
          String sql="insert into OT_PURCHASE_ORDER (part_no,ITEM_DESCRIPTION,QUANTITY,AMOUNT,PAYMENT_MODE,SUPPLIER_ID,PO_DATE,EXP_DATE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
          pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);             
          pst.setString(1, table_po.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
          pst.setString(2, table_po.getModel().getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
          pst.setString(3, table_po.getModel().getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
          pst.setString(4, table_po.getModel().getValueAt(i, 3).toString());
          pst.setString(5, (String)cbo_payment.getSelectedItem());
          int index=((int)list.get(cbo_supplier.getSelectedIndex()));
          pst.setInt(6, index);
          //pst.setString(7, lblCash.getText());
          pst.setString(7, ((JTextField)txt_Expdate.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
          pst.setString(8, ((JTextField)txt_date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());

          pst.execute();
          pst.close();
           sql="select max (po_id) as POIDfrom fm_credit_sale";
           pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          rs=pst.executeQuery();
          if(rs.next()){
              transactionCounter.add(rs.getInt("POID"));

          }
          transactioncounter++;
    }

     for(int i=0;i<saleListCounter;i++){             
         table_po.getModel().setValueAt(null, i, 0);
         table_po.getModel().setValueAt(null, i, 1);
         table_po.getModel().setValueAt(null, i, 2);
         table_po.getModel().setValueAt(null, i, 3);
         table_po.getModel().setValueAt(null, i, 4);
     }

     total=saleListCounter=0;
     lblCash.setText(null);

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAVED SUCCESSFULLY");
   }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }    
}
```

Comment: That means you're trying to access something on index `0` that isn't there (this collection is empty). Insert something first, before trying to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this part of your code must be giving you an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0` :-

```
 if(table_po.getModel().getValueAt(0, 0)==null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select products before saving");
        return;
  }
```

Use this code :-

```
try{
 if(table_po.getModel().getValueAt(0, 0)==null){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select products before saving");
        return;
  }
}catch(Exception e){ return; }
```

Further notes : Java gives you the stack trace of the exception too. You can get the line number where the exception is occurring and you will be able to identify the problem. Use `e.printStackTrace();` to get the stack trace in your console.